# plot a histogram with three y axes and one x axis in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I am trying to plot a barplot/histogram with one x axis (method) and three y axes (RequirementT, RequirementN, RequirementU). Here is a link to my full data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aBRy2uf34kjWQAo8nUDMnuAEHPR4XBMD/view?usp=sharing

I am using the following python code:

```
# Load the Pandas libraries with alias 'pd' 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Read data from file 'filename.csv' 
# (in the same directory that your python process is based)
# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later) 
df = pd.read_csv("chessMethodReq.txt") 
# Preview the first 5 lines of the loaded data 
df.head()


ax=df.plot.bar(x='method', y=['RequirementT', 'RequirementN', 'RequirementU'])
```

The problem is that I end up with this crazy looking x axis

[image]

I imagine it is because there is too much information going from 1, 2, 3, ..., 752 on my x axis. I would like to use intervals for my x axis going from:
[0,100][100,200][200, 300][300, 400][400,500], [500, 600], [600,700], [700,800]

Comment: Your main problem is that you plot strings. Make sure to plot numbers instead.

Comment: I am not plotting strings, I am plotting numbers, you can look at my input file for every method, I want a bar plot showing the amount of T, N and U requirements

Comment: Oh sorry. This is a bar plot. Pandas bar plots are categorical. You can use matplotlib bar plots instead.